# xhr.response returns null on the content field with POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a POST request to the server but it ends up sending null content to the database which means the request is going through but the content field is not being updated. I'm getting my content value from a React form. Any  kind of help will be greatly appreciated

```
const lookup = (method, endpoint, callback, data) => {
  let jsonData;
  if (data) {
    jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${endpoint}`;

  const csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.responseType = "json";
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  if (csrftoken) {
    // xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
  }

  // function called when xhr transaction completes successfully.
  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response);
    console.log(xhr.status);
    callback(xhr.response, xhr.status);
  };

  xhr.onerror = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    callback({message: "The request was an error"}, 400);
  };

  xhr.send(jsonData);
};;


const createTweet = (newTweet, callback) => {
    lookup("POST", "tweets/create/", callback, {content: newTweet})
}

function Tweets(props) {
  const textAreaRef = React.createRef()
  const [newTweets, setNewTweets] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log(event);
    const newTweet = textAreaRef.current.value;
    let tempNewTweets = [...newTweets];

    //change this to a server side call
    createTweet(newTweet, (response, status) => {
      console.log(response, status);
      console.log(newTweet);
      if (status === 201) {
        tempNewTweets.unshift(response);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        alert("An error occured please try again")
      }
    })

    setNewTweets(tempNewTweets)
    textAreaRef.current.value = "";
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row my-3">
        <div className="col-md-4 mx-auto col-12">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <textarea
              ref={textAreaRef}
              required={true}
              className="form-control"
              name="tweet"
            ></textarea>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary my-3">
              Tweet
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <TweetsList newTweets={newTweets}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I log the response all other fields (likes and id) are okay but the content field is null

Comment: you need to set the `content-length` http header as well. Also, ensure your jsonData has value in proper json format, print it in console before calling the `send` method.

Comment: After typing **hey** in the form. This is what showed up when I tried to console jsonData ```{"content":"hey"}```

Comment: Then check your api implementation for the api /tweets/create, whether it is receiving the request payload correctly and inserting to database. Inside your `onload` event handler, print the `status` property of the request. It should be 200 or 201 if api sends success response.

Comment: Why have you not used `fetch` api to make the POST calls to your web api? That is more [modern](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/01/react-fetch-http-post-request-examples) than using xhr.

Comment: My payload in network shows the exact content I typed in, the preview shows ```content: null```

Comment: Header shows ```201 Created```. Maybe i'll consider using ```fetch```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244263/discussion-between-jumba-mark-and-anand-sowmithiran).